# Repeated text with overlapping in pattern for regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex. Suppose that I have an input like this:

> #tag0#ABCD###tag1#EFGH###tag2#IJKL## ...

The repeated sequence is like `#tagx#<DATA>##`. The tag field only contains letters and numbers.

And I want to extract tags like this:

```
{
 "tag0": "ABCD",
 "tag1": "EFGH",
 "tag2": "IJKL",
 ...
}
```

I tried something like `#[a-zA-Z0-9]*#(.*)##` but it gives all data except the first tag.

Comment: Try `#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)##` https://regex101.com/r/FJoXHq/1 or else use a non greedy `.*?`

Comment: `dict(re.findall(r'#([^#]+)#(.*?)(?=##|\Z)', s))` (`|\Z` is only necessary if the value may have no trailing `##`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex and a non-regex approach here:

```
import re
s = "#tag0#ABCD###tag1#EFGH###tag2#IJKL##"
print ( dict(re.findall(r'#([^#]+)#(.*?)(?:##|\Z)', s)) )
# => {'tag0': 'ABCD', 'tag1': 'EFGH', 'tag2': 'IJKL'}
print ( dict([(x.split('#')[0],x.split('#')[-1]) for x in s.strip('#').split('###')]) )
# => {'tag0': 'ABCD', 'tag1': 'EFGH', 'tag2': 'IJKL'}
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JGZBKD)

The `#([^#]+)#(.*?)(?=##|\Z)` regex matches:

- `#` - a `#` char
- `([^#]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `#`
- `#` - a `#` char
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 2: any chars, 0 or more, as few as possible
- `(?:##|\Z)` - up to the first occurrence of `##` or end of string.

If `##` are always present at the end of string, remove `|\Z`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/anrWey/1).

The non-regex approach means stripping the `#` chars on both string ends, splitting with `###` and then splitting each item with `#`.